# Reg-ex to check if timestamp contains odd seconds

Tags: regex

I have a log line as follows -

```
[Thread-2505_GOOGLE_INT_20170424155901301f9e61-1493049600619-NSRLM_2_1_RTDSDL_39088504_2_R_1234,23234] 2017-04-24 12:00:01 : S:XXXX-SSSS-SSSSSS A:Availability M:INT_20170424155901301f9e61-1493049600619-NSRLM_2_1_RTSDL_39088504_2_R_1 CMD: [<?xml version="1.0" ?><AvailabilityRequestV2 xmlns="http://xml.google.com" siteid="1470249" apikey="SFGSDGSDFSDFGSFG" async="false" waittime="5"><Type>4</Type><Id>460573</Id><Radius>0</Radius><Latitude>0.0</Latitude><Longitude>0.0</Longitude><CheckIn>2017-10-01</CheckIn><CheckOut>2017-10-17</CheckOut><Rooms>1</Rooms><Adults>2</Adults><Children>0</Children><Language>en-us</Language><Currency>000</Currency></AvailabilityRequestV2>]
```

Which has a timestamp as "2017-04-24 12:00:01". I am trying to frame a reg-ex to check if the time contains odd number of second (above matches).

Any help?

Comment: Use: `\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d[13579]`

Comment: That worked! Thanks!

Comment: post it as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To detect odd numbered second you can use this regex:

```
\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d[13579]
```

Anything ending with `[13579]` will be an odd number.